# How to publish a php website privately so I can make tests?

Tags: tls, php, webserver

I want to publish my website as http secure connection but I want to keep it private so only I can view it. I want to prepare and test its security before its official release.

Is there any service providing this kind of thing or can anyone give me advice? I’m new to publishing websites and their securities.

If I'm asking something wrong please let me know the details. I want to learn the procedures before releasing a website.

Comment: How to host a website is not an infosec concern. To limit who can see it, you would not host it publicly to test. You host on a local machine. Look for "self-signed TLS" guides if you want HTTPS.

Comment: Google "setting up a staging environment".  Easiest route is to publish to your own machine.  (You can then use your own local ip to test it... downside is you may end up adding trust to a self-signed certificate.  Secure that cert if you decide to trust it.)  This is something in between debugging in the IDE, and publishing to live site... generally you'd only use staging servers for teams of people to access/test.  If it's only you, testing while in your IDE should be good enough.

Comment: Does it really have to be HTTPS? Does it need to use a HTTPS certificate that is trusted by default or are self-signed certificates acceptable? Does it have to be reachable from other devices or just your PC? // Basically, you’ll have to set up a web server with PHP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a VPS (with public IP) and containers to achieve that. It requires advanced and sophisticated skills to keep it secure. The core tools you would need are docker, docker-compose, and traefik to create private networks on VPS where only you (or the users you want) have access.

Below is the documentation, how-to, and getting started for traefik

https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/

Comment: This seems like artificial overkill. Lots of hosting companies provide site password-protection for this use case, so as not to require advanced and sophisticated skills. Or needing to learn 2 separate advanced technologies just to run pentests. Heck, a single line in the firewall would be perfect.

Comment: @schroeder i agree. It is a lot of work to maintain this solution besides meeting software/application development obligations. One must have a lot of time on its  hands to maintain it.